# Group by and condition in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

If the participant has both "success" and "error" status, need to return as "Partial_error", otherwise return as it is.

I prepared a query below which is working. I think it's not correct way. Can you please advise?

```
SELECT
    T.PARTICIPANT_ID,
    (CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'PARTIAL_ERROR'
         WHEN ISNULL(MAX(RLV.DESCRIPTION), '') = '' THEN MAX(T.LINE_STATUS)
         ELSE MAX(RLV.DESCRIPTION)
     END) LINE_STATUS
FROM 
    (SELECT
         PARTICIPANT_ID,
         wp.LINE_STATUS
     FROM 
         [PROSPER].[PR_WKDAY_PAYFILE_PARTICIPANTS] wp
     WHERE 
         wp.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED'
     GROUP BY 
         PARTICIPANT_ID, wp.LINE_STATUS) T
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[LOOKUP_VALUE] rlv ON rlv.VALUE = T.LINE_STATUS
GROUP BY
    T.PARTICIPANT_ID
```

Comment: can you provide some data example?

Comment: Please add few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with your query. you could avoid removing duplicates by doing COUNT(DISTINCT LINE_STATUS), but otherwise not sure what you don't like about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use subquery in the `FROM` clause. Your query could be shortened to

```
SELECT PARTICIPANT_ID,
       (CASE
          WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT wp.LINE_STATUS) > 1 THEN 'PARTIAL_ERROR'
          ELSE ISNULL(MAX(RLV.DESCRIPTION), MAX(wp.LINE_STATUS))
        END) AS LINE_STATUS
FROM   [PROSPER].[PR_WKDAY_PAYFILE_PARTICIPANTS] wp
         LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LOOKUP_VALUE] rlv ON rlv.VALUE = wp.LINE_STATUS
WHERE  wp.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED'
GROUP BY PARTICIPANT_ID
```